# calculate fourth value automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

EDIT2: I removed the input validations, so now values don't get corrupted. 
Added more functions to onkeyup method. However, if for eg, I enter three values, for Widht, GSM and Weight, Length will be calculated but since all functions are in on key up, along with length, other values change as well.

How do I make it so that when Length is being calculated, other values don't alter?

---

EDIT: For eg, if value for Length, Width and GSM is provided, then value for Weight will be assigned { formula: Length * Width * GSM/3100 }

if value for Width, GSM and Weight are given, then Length should be calculated { formula: (Weight * 3100) / width * GSM }

and so on.

I have four input boxes, What I want is when the user puts in any of the three boxes the fourth value should generate automatically in the fourth box.
Right now my code works when there is a fixed box in which we have to get the fourth value

New HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Paper Calc 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/test.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/CALC.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div id = "case_one"  class="calcoptions sizemod">

    <h5>1. To find the weight (in <b>Kilograms</b>) of a ream containing 500 sheets of a given size in <b>inches</b> and <b>Gram-Weight.</b></h5> 
    <br>    

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">


    Length: <input type="number" step="0.01" name="length_in" id="length" placeholder="Length(inch)"  onkeyup="fun(); fun2(); fun3();">inch
    <br><br>

    Width: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" step="0.01" name="width_in" id="width" placeholder="Width(inch)"  onkeyup="fun(); fun2(); fun4();">inch
    <br><br>

    GSM: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="extraSpace">&nbsp;</span><input type="number"    step="0.01" name="length_in" id="GSM" placeholder="GSM" onkeyup="fun(); fun3(); fun4();"> <!-- <button type = "button" name = "calc2" class = 'btnclass' id="cal2" onclick="func2()"> calc2-->
    </button>
    <br><br>

    Weight: <input type="number" step = "0.01" name="Weight_Kg" id = "weight" onkeyup="fun2(); fun3(); fun4();"> <!-- KG <button type = "button" name = "calc1" id="cal1" class = 'btnclass' onclick="func1()">
        calc1 -->
    </button> 
    <br><br> 






    </div>
 <p id='err'></p>

</body>
</html>
```

New JS:

```
function fun()
{
  var l = document.getElementById('length').value;
  var w = document.getElementById('width').value;
  var g = document.getElementById('GSM').value;

  if (l && w && g)
  {
    var wt = document.getElementById('weight');
    var calculate = (eval(l)*eval(w)*eval(g))/3100;
    wt.value = calculate.toFixed(2);
  }
};

function fun2()
{
  var l = document.getElementById('length').value;
  var w = document.getElementById('width').value;
  var wt = document.getElementById('weight').value;

  if (l && w && wt)
  {
    var g = document.getElementById('GSM');
    var calculate = (eval(wt)*3100)/(eval(l)*eval(w));
    g.value = calculate.toFixed(2);
  }
};

function fun3()
{
  var l = document.getElementById('length').value;
  var wt = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  var g = document.getElementById('GSM').value;

  if (l && g && wt)
  {
    var w = document.getElementById('width');
    var calculate = (eval(wt)*3100)/(eval(l)*eval(g));
    w.value = calculate.toFixed(2);
  }
};

function fun4()
{
  var w = document.getElementById('width').value;
  var wt = document.getElementById('weight').value;
  var g = document.getElementById('GSM').value;

  if (w && g && wt)
  {
    var l = document.getElementById('length');
    var calculate = (eval(wt)*3100)/(eval(w)*eval(g));
    l.value = calculate.toFixed(2);
  }
};
```

```js
function calculateWeightInInches() {
  var Length = document.getElementById("txt_weight").value;
  var width = document.getElementById("txt_width").value;
  var GSM = document.getElementById("txt_GSM").value;
  var calculate = (Length * width * GSM) / 3100;
  var result = document.getElementById("txt_Result");

  // if (Length < 0)
  // {
  //  document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = 'Incorrect Length!';
  // }

  error = document.getElementById('err_1');

  if (calculate < 0 || width > 300 || width < 1 || GSM < 5 || GSM > 800 || Length < 1 || Length > 99) {
    result.value = 0;
    error.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    result.value = calculate.toFixed(2);
    error.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div id="case_one" class="calcoptions sizemod">

    <h5>1. To find the weight (in <b>Kilograms</b>) of a ream containing 500 sheets of a given size in <b>inches</b> and <b>Gram-Weight.</b></h5>
    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">


        Length: <input type="number" step="0.01" name="length_in" id="txt_weight" placeholder="Length(inch)" min="1" max="99" onkeyup="calculateWeightInInches();">inch
        <br><br> Width: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" step="0.01" name="width_in" id="txt_width" placeholder="Width(inch)" min="1" max='300' onkeyup="calculateWeightInInches();">inch
        <br><br> GSM: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="extraSpace">&nbsp;</span><input type="number" min="5" max="800" step="0.01" name="length_in" id="txt_GSM" placeholder="GSM" onkeyup="calculateWeightInInches();">
        <br><br> Weight: <input type="number" step="0.01" name="Weight_Kg" id="txt_Result" readonly="readonly">KG
        <br><br>


      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p id="err_1" style="display: none;">

          Valid Range: <br> L = 1 to 99 inch <br> W = 1 to 99 inch <br> GSM = 5 to 800 <br><br> Formula: (Length * width * GSM) / 3100

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="case_two" class="calcoptions sizemod">
```

I am trying by putting another function in onkeyup but it ruins the code.
[because values keep changing]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `I am trying by putting another function in onkey but it ruins the code.` What does this mean? Do you get errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: You should use `oninput` event listener instead of `onkeyup` inside the `HTML` tag. This will also give you function calls for if value is changed by mouse click or any other way.
Also please elaborate on what is actually the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateWeightInInches() {
           var Length = document.getElementById("txt_weight").value;
           var width = document.getElementById("txt_width").value;
           var GSM = document.getElementById("txt_GSM").value;
           var calculate = (Length * width * GSM) / 3100;
           var result = document.getElementById("txt_Result");

           // if (Length < 0)
           // {
           //   document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = 'Incorrect Length!';
           // }

           error = document.getElementById('err_1');

           if(calculate < 0 || width > 300 || width < 1 || GSM < 5 || GSM > 800 || Length < 1 || Length > 99)
           {
            result.value = 0;
            error.style.display = 'block'; 
           }

           else
           {
               if(Length && width && GSM) {
                var GSMElement = document.getElementById("txt_GSM");
                var lengthElement = document.getElementById("txt_weight");
                var widthElement = document.getElementById("txt_width");
                var elementsArray = [GSMElement,widthElement,lengthElement]
                elementsArray.forEach(function(ele){
                    ele.addEventListener('change', function() {
                        result.value = calculate.toFixed(2);
                        error.style.display = 'none';   

                    })
                })

               }
           }       
       }
```

Comment: Please explain what was the problem and what changes you have done.

Comment: First I confirm all three values not null, Then i add `eventListner` to GSM(third input), then change value in fourth input. I just change code last `else` condition

Comment: Don't know, if its working properly or not. But whenever you post something, try to include what was not working, how you fixed, etc. So that the knowledge is transferred. :)